# how to change uinavigation controller back button action

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have a `UINavigationController` and I have to keep the the default back button "the back arrow style" I just want to ask if I can change the back button action without build new one and change its style

Comment: I don't get it, do you want to change its style, or its action ?

Comment: I want to change the action only

Comment: What's the new action ? Because if you just want to skip a view in the views stack (for example), you don't need a new button.

Comment: i just want to change the animation of the return back ie. change the default navigation behavior

Comment: Well, you need a new button :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK you cannot change the action of the default back button itself but you can place a UIBarButtonItem as leftBarButtonItem there and assign your own action.

If there is a leftBarButtonItem defined then this is shown and not the default back button.

However, keep the GUI guidelines in mind when doing tricks like this.

Comment: Yup, agree about Apple's HIG, changing the action of a standard UI element will probably get the app rejected from the AppStore !

Comment: Yes. Unless of course the action just adds some functionallity, probaby even not visible to the user, and does not change the general behaviour of the app. There is no need for having "BACK" in that button or for the name of the underlying view controller. That is just recommended. But it should go back there from a navigation point of view.

Comment: @OmarFreewan, if you really just need to add some functionaltiy there then consider using viewWillDisappear or viewWillAppear (or the corresponding DID methods) of the appropriate view controllers. However, they may not nessessarily match your needs becaus they are called always when a view appears or disappers.

Comment: Yes I agree with you @HermannKlecker the viewWillAppear/Disappear is not helpful here

Answer (score 1):

No. If you want a custom back button, you have to create a custom UIBarButtonItem, then assign it to the appropriate property:

```
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = myCustomBackItem;
```

Answer (score 0):

The back button in UINavigationBar is generated automatically as soon as u Push a new UIView. In order for you to customize the Back button is to Create a new UIToolBar + a UIBarButtonItem with custom view.

Code below is the sample to use a custom UIBarButtonItem in UIToolBar.

```
    // create button
UIButton* backButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:101]; // left-pointing shape!
[backButton addTarget:self action:@selector(backAction) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[backButton setTitle:@"Back" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

// create button item -- possible because UIButton subclasses UIView!
UIBarButtonItem* backItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:backButton];

// add to toolbar, or to a navbar (you should only have one of these!)
[toolbar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObject:backItem]];
navItem.leftBarButtonItem = backItem;
```

Link below is the design of iOS buttons in PSD format for further modifications.

http://www.chrisandtennille.com/pictures/backbutton.psd

Answer (score 0):

You can make custom button and can make action on it but you can not change default backButton action.....

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = getBackBtn;
```

Answer (score 0):

The UINavigationController sends a message to it's delegate when it pushes and pops a ViewController.

You can find out when the back button gets pressed by implementing the following and adding `<UINavigationControllerDelegate>` in your .h file

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    self.navigationController.delegate = self;
}

-(void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
    self.navigationController.delegate = nil;
}

-(void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController
     willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController 
                   animated:(BOOL)animated{

    //Test here if the View Controller being shown next is right below the current
    //    ViewController in the navigation stack
    //
    //Test by:
    // 1. comparing classes, or
    // 2. checking for a unique tag that you previously assigned, or
    // 3. comparing against the [navigationController viewControllers][n-2] 
    //        where n is the number of items in the array

    if ([viewController isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"ViewControllerClassThatGetsPushedOnBACK")){
        //back button has been pressed
    }

    if (viewController.tag == myUniqueTagIdentifier){
        //back button has been pressed
    }

    if ([navigationController.viewControllers[navigationController.viewControllers.count-2]==viewController]){
        //back button has been pressed
    }
}
```

[Apple Docs UINavigationController Class Reference:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006934-CH3-SW16)

> The root view controller is at index 0 in the array, the back view
>   controller is at index n-2, and the top controller is at index n-1,
>   where n is the number of items in the array.

Comment: @Jesse_Gumpo how do you know you're going backwards? In all my testing, the provided viewController is the view controller to be presented, and the other common places (topViewController, visibleViewController) are all already showing the same thing viewController is showing.  I'm trying to do something specific when the user backs up as opposed to when they move forward into this view controller, so knowing "direction" is critical.  There's a hidden _disappearingViewController which I bet has what I need, but it's not an official API....